# How to append external JSON in plain HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I'm trying to output some values taken from an API (JSON-formatted). And can't find a solution on how to grab the JSON tags and make them turn into HTML. JSON example [here](http://pastebin.com/sKz8MW4z).
How do I get that JSON to turn out as DIV-tags, paragraphs and headings?

Answer (score 1):

you need to code that. there are already existing libraries who can help you there: http://json2html.com/

Comment: I tried JSON2HTML, hard. Should be a tutorial on it. But that just what I think.

Comment: Your example JSON is pretty simple. You could probably achieve the same result as using JSON2HTML with a simple recursive function that loops over your JSON object and all of its sub-objects, etc., and uses jQuery (or even just plain Javascript) to append all the elements into a container div element (`var container = $('<div/>')` in jQuery), then append that div to the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's no 1-to-1 mapping between JSON and HTML. You will have to do that manually depending on the JSON structure. So for example you could access inidividual elements of your object like this:

```
result.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.ID
```